403 Forbidden error, while rendering Pdf using react-pdf and Uploadthings to store pdf
enter image description here
this is the core.ts
import { db } from "@/db";
import { getKindeServerSession } from "@kinde-oss/kinde-auth-nextjs/server";
import { createUploadthing, type FileRouter } from "uploadthing/next";

const f = createUploadthing();

export const ourFileRouter = {
  pdfUploader: f({ pdf: { maxFileSize: "4MB" } })
    .middleware(async ({ req }) => {
      const { getUser } = getKindeServerSession();
      const user = await getUser();

      if (!user || !user.id) throw new Error("Unauthorized");
      return { userId: user.id };
    })
    .onUploadComplete(async ({ metadata, file }) => {
      const createdFile = await db.file.create({
        data: {
          key: file.key,
          name: file.name,
          userId: metadata.userId,
          url: `https://uploadthing-prod.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/${file.key}`,
          uploadStatus: "PROCESSING",
        },
      });
    }),
} satisfies FileRouter;

export type OurFileRouter = typeof ourFileRouter;


and this is route.ts
`import { createRouteHandler } from "uploadthing/next";
import { ourFileRouter } from "./core";
// Export routes for Next App Router
export const { GET, POST } = createRouteHandler({
router: ourFileRouter,
// Apply an (optional) custom config:
// config: { ... },
});
`
and this is the tsx file where iam trying to render pdf
"use client";

import { useToast } from "@/hooks/use-toast";
import { Loader2 } from "lucide-react";
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from "react-pdf";
import "react-pdf/dist/Page/AnnotationLayer.css";
import "react-pdf/dist/Page/TextLayer.css";

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;

interface PdfRendererProps {
  url: string;
}

const PdfRenderer = ({ url }: PdfRendererProps) => {
  console.log(url);
  const { toast } = useToast();
  return (
    <div className="w-full bg-white rounded-md shadow flex flex-col items-center">
      <div className="h-14 w-full border-b border-zince-200 flex items-center justify-between px-2">
        <div className="flex items-center gap-1.5">top bar</div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex-1 w-full max-h-screen">
        <div>
          <Document
            file={url}
            className="max-h-full"
            loading={
              <div className="flex justify-center">
                <Loader2 className="my-24 h-6 w-6 animate-spin" />
              </div>
            }
            onLoadError={() => {
              toast({
                title: "error loading PDF",
                description: "Please try again later",
                variant: "destructive",
              });
            }}
          >
            <Page pageNumber={1} />
          </Document>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default PdfRenderer;


Iam trying to render the pdf file
